# .Net-Core Controller action won't bind child complex type in model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

This is the action I try to bind the model:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveNewBusiness(NewBusinessVm newBusiness)
    {

    }
```

This is the model:

```
    public class NewBusinessVm 
    {
       public NewBusinessVm()
       {

       }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ImageViewModel MainImage { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> CategorySelections { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> LocationSelections { get; set; }
    public string LocationStr { get; set; }
    public List<int> FacilitiesIDs { get; set; }
    public string GoogleAddress { get; set; }
    public string FriendlyAddress { get; set; }
    public string GooglePlaceID { get; set; }
    public string Lat { get; set; }
    public string Long { get; set; }
    public int MinPrice { get; set; }
    public int MaxPrice { get; set; }
}
```

The problematic property that won't bind is `MainImage`:

```
  public class ImageViewModel
    {
        public bool IsParent { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public List<ImageViewModel> ChildImages { get; set; }
        public int? ImageFamilyId { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Alt { get; set; }
        public string Width { get; set; }
        public string Height { get; set; }
        public string Sizes { get; set; }
        public bool IsThumbNail { get; set; }
        public int Bytes { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateTime { get; set; }
    }
```

I add the `MainImage` to the data.
On the client side I tried all these 3 methods:

```
        //#1
        var data = $form.serializeArray();
        data[data.length] = { name: "MainImage", value: mainImageObj };
        console.log(data);
        AjaxModule.Ajax(url, data, options);

        //#2
        var dataJson = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(dataJson);
        AjaxModule.Ajax(url, dataJson, options);

        //#3
        var data2 = $form.serialize();
        data2 += "&MainImage=" + JSON.stringify(mainImageObj);
        console.log(data2);
        AjaxModule.Ajax(url, data2, options);
```

First option object looks like this:
[image]

Second option:

```
[{"name":"Name","value":"BusinessName example"},{"name":"CategoryID","value":"80"},{"name":"Description","value":""},{"name":"GooglePlaceID","value":"ChIJy9AOJGrKM5QR23I19T-HKD0"},{"name":"Long","value":""},{"name":"Lat","value":""},{"name":"GoogleAddress","value":"La Posta, Cordoba, Argentina"},{"name":"FriendlyAddress","value":"Río Primero,La Posta"},{"name":"__RequestVerificationToken","value":"CfDJ8E3zPSvylsxAsVq_mjBa9qQxnItdTOHxZje0mUebkKW5pH2K2ZUkB_Flg3XJsUQh_8hxmqGvUJo_hLuQIz6xOiFR1Y5HCDeGmGGKFSM2h1cHGfGkr7SBkIkZr4ImqCDRiaaRmy0x1taJyFmcqRpXMVSBnBN5pcjWkqqNhuGYL09KKD2xFJwk1Tbhcyb7d2YEPw"},{"name":"MainImage","value":{"IsParent":true,"ImageUrl":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dzpwse6vo/image/upload/v1587727444/Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx.jpg","FileName":"Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx","Width":720,"Height":960,"CreateTime":"2020-04-24T11:24:04Z","Bytes":50450,"ChildImages":[{"IsParent":false,"ImageUrl":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dzpwse6vo/image/upload/c_crop,g_auto,h_350,q_auto,w_1600/v1587727444/Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx.jpg","FileName":"Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx","Width":720,"Height":350,"CreateTime":"2020-04-24T11:24:04Z","Bytes":21629},{"IsParent":false,"ImageUrl":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dzpwse6vo/image/upload/c_scale,q_auto,w_0.8/v1587727444/Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx.jpg","FileName":"Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx","Width":576,"Height":768,"CreateTime":"2020-04-24T11:24:04Z","Bytes":38069},{"IsParent":false,"ImageUrl":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dzpwse6vo/image/upload/c_scale,q_auto,w_0.6/v1587727444/Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx.jpg","FileName":"Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx","Width":432,"Height":576,"CreateTime":"2020-04-24T11:24:04Z","Bytes":25138},{"IsParent":false,"ImageUrl":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dzpwse6vo/image/upload/c_scale,q_auto,w_0.4/v1587727444/Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx.jpg","FileName":"Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx","Width":288,"Height":384,"CreateTime":"2020-04-24T11:24:04Z","Bytes":14803},{"IsParent":false,"ImageUrl":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dzpwse6vo/image/upload/c_scale,q_auto,w_0.2/v1587727444/Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx.jpg","FileName":"Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx","Width":144,"Height":192,"CreateTime":"2020-04-24T11:24:04Z","Bytes":5285,"IsThumbnail":true}]}}]
```

Third Option:

```
Name=BusinessName%20example&CategoryID=80&Description=&GooglePlaceID=ChIJy9AOJGrKM5QR23I19T-HKD0&Long=&Lat=&GoogleAddress=La%20Posta%2C%20Cordoba%2C%20Argentina&FriendlyAddress=R%C3%ADo%20Primero%2CLa%20Posta&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8E3zPSvylsxAsVq_mjBa9qQxnItdTOHxZje0mUebkKW5pH2K2ZUkB_Flg3XJsUQh_8hxmqGvUJo_hLuQIz6xOiFR1Y5HCDeGmGGKFSM2h1cHGfGkr7SBkIkZr4ImqCDRiaaRmy0x1taJyFmcqRpXMVSBnBN5pcjWkqqNhuGYL09KKD2xFJwk1Tbhcyb7d2YEPw&MainImage={"IsParent":true,"ImageUrl":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dzpwse6vo/image/upload/v1587727444/Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx.jpg","FileName":"Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx","Width":720,"Height":960,"CreateTime":"2020-04-24T11:24:04Z","Bytes":50450,"ChildImages":[{"IsParent":false,"ImageUrl":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dzpwse6vo/image/upload/c_crop,g_auto,h_350,q_auto,w_1600/v1587727444/Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx.jpg","FileName":"Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx","Width":720,"Height":350,"CreateTime":"2020-04-24T11:24:04Z","Bytes":21629},{"IsParent":false,"ImageUrl":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dzpwse6vo/image/upload/c_scale,q_auto,w_0.8/v1587727444/Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx.jpg","FileName":"Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx","Width":576,"Height":768,"CreateTime":"2020-04-24T11:24:04Z","Bytes":38069},{"IsParent":false,"ImageUrl":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dzpwse6vo/image/upload/c_scale,q_auto,w_0.6/v1587727444/Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx.jpg","FileName":"Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx","Width":432,"Height":576,"CreateTime":"2020-04-24T11:24:04Z","Bytes":25138},{"IsParent":false,"ImageUrl":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dzpwse6vo/image/upload/c_scale,q_auto,w_0.4/v1587727444/Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx.jpg","FileName":"Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx","Width":288,"Height":384,"CreateTime":"2020-04-24T11:24:04Z","Bytes":14803},{"IsParent":false,"ImageUrl":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dzpwse6vo/image/upload/c_scale,q_auto,w_0.2/v1587727444/Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx.jpg","FileName":"Businesses/44637/noyc0lpgto9t2p1j15kx","Width":144,"Height":192,"CreateTime":"2020-04-24T11:24:04Z","Bytes":5285,"IsThumbnail":true}]}
```

I tried to change the signature to 
`public JsonResult SaveNewBusiness([FromBody]NewBusinessVm newBusiness)`

and also to:
`public JsonResult SaveNewBusiness([FromForm]NewBusinessVm newBusiness)`

All the properties binds as expected except for this one.
Any Help, is it possible?

Comment: I think you need to have the property name in your `json`: so it would be `{ MainImage: { etc..... } }`

Answer (score 0):

Your `json` format is **incorrect**.

You must change the `json` to this

```
{
  "MainImage": {
    "IsParent": true,
    "ImageUrl": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dzpws1e6vo/image/upload/v1587657844/Businesses/44637/q1lgkqgwpwp7zy1obtpwn.jpg",
    "FileName": "Businesses/44637/qlgkqgwpwp7zy11obtpwn",
    "Width": 960,
    "Height": 720,
    "CreateTime": "2020-04-23T16:04:04Z",
    "Bytes": 181783,
    "ChildImages": [{
        "IsParent": false,
        "ImageUrl": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dzpwse6vo/image/upload/c_crop,g_auto,h_350,q_auto,w_1600/v15876517844/Businesses/44637/qlgkqgwpwp7zy1o1btpwn.jpg",
        "FileName": "Businesses/44637/qlgkqgwpwp7z1y1obtpwn",
        "Width": 960,
        "Height": 350,
        "CreateTime": "2020-04-23T16:04:04Z",
        "Bytes": 78322
    }]
}
```

or change the input model to this

```cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveNewBusiness(ImageViewModel imageViewModel)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing and matching things here. A form will be sent as `x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is basically just string key-value pairs. Setting a JSON object as the value of one of those pairs won't cause that JSON to be deserialized into an object when sent this way, because it's not known or indicated in any way that it's JSON; it's just a string like any other string. Additionally, the entire object here won't bind, anyways, because `FromBody` requires something like `application/json`, not `x-www-form-urlencoded`. For the latter, you'd need `FromForm`.

If you want to accept JSON, then you'll need to use AJAX to send the post (as an HTML form has no ability to do that), and you'll need to actually send it encoded as JSON, not using hidden inputs with JSON-like strings as values.

If you want to continue to post via a form, then you'll either need to include inputs for each of the properties on main image (instead of just one input with the entire object as the value), or you will need to bind it to a string property, and manually come back and deserialized it yourself into an object.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I post a form without a complex object I do it like so:

```
var data = $form.serialize();
AjaxModule.Ajax(url, data, options);
```

But because of the complex object I had to manipulate to form inputs to a clean javascript object like so:

```
    //#1 form elements into name:value object
    var data = $form.serializeArray();
    data[data.length] = { name: "MainImage", value: mainImageObj };

    //#2 Create a clean JS Object
    var myObj = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        myObj[data[j]["name"]] = data[j]["value"];
    }

    AjaxModule.Ajax(url, myObj, options);
```

Works!
Thank you Partick(aka:poke)